# How to scale down images efficiently in css?

Tags: css, scale

What I've done currently to scale down my image is to manually adjust them in css. The original picture is 1920 x 1219. Though, I find this to be highly inefficient, tedious and inaccurate. Can anyone help me find a better solution?

```
.planePic{
    width: 700px;
    height: 500px;
}
```

Comment: You only have to set width OR height, the other will scale automatically

Comment: Oh that actually works, never thought the solution was so straight forward. Tysm!

Comment: i prefer using an image editor and make your image which size you want because every image make website heavier, increase internet usage, make website slower and lower the seo performance